# Oracle Forms 10g - Closing IE after opening msg file

Tags: oracleforms

We are using web.show_document built-in in Oracle forms (web.show_document('file:///file_name','_blank') ) to open outlook msg files stored at a location.

While opening msg files, a new IE browser gets open along with msg file. User need to close this additional browser.

Answer (score 0):

I infer that you do not wish the separate IE browser to be opened in the first place?  If that is the case, then there is another option than what I present below.  Read on.

Option 1:

From the Forms documentation, the target ("_blank") parameter has a few different possible values.

---

target  Datatype is VARCHAR2. Specifies one of the following targets:

- '_self' Causes the document to load
  into the same frame or window as the
  source document.
- '_parent' Causes the target document
  to load into the parent window or
  frameset containing the hypertext
  reference. If the reference is in a
  window or top-level frame, it is
  equivalent to the target _self.
- '_top' Causes the document to load
  into the window containing the
  hypertext link, replacing any frames
  currently displayed in the window.
- '_blank' (default) Causes the
  document to load into a new, unnamed
  top-level window.

Note that these targets are lowercase and enclosed in single quotation marks.

---

Option 2:

If you would rather not have an IE window open up at all, there is a package in `WEBUTIL.PLL` called `WEBUTIL_HOST`.  It would allow you to open a file from the perspective of the client.  I am going out on a limb here an making an assumption that the URI you mentioning as 'file:///file_name' is a file path that is likely accessible from the client already.
Hope this helps, I made a few assumptions here.  If you provide some more info on the specific situation, that would be helpful.